# Apply default AuthorizationPolicy even when Authorize attribute with Roles is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I apply my global policy like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(...).Build();
});
```

When I use `[Authorize]` on controller it works fine but if I specify roles with `[Authorize(Roles = ...)]` my default policy is ignored. How can I make so that my policy is applied globally to all endpoints that use `[Authorize]` attribute regardless of `Roles` specified? I need an "and" combination of my default policy and `[Authorize]` attribute setup.

Comment: Applying multiple `[Authorize]` tags should work as an "and" combination. What happens when you place both the empty and role-based authorize attributes on at the same time?

Comment: I don't need to apply multiple `Authorize` attributes, I want to combine `Authorize` attributes with a `DefaultPolicy`.

Comment: That is the question I was posing: if you apply both `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(Roles=...)]` attributes at the same time, my expectation is that it would provide an "and" condition that evaluates both the default policy and the role policy. If that doesn't cover your need, I can provide an answer with some additional suggestions or options.

Comment: I don't want to apply a second `[Authorize]` attribute everywhere in my code. Instead I want to use a policy that is applied globally as an "and" condition to all existing attributes. Currently it works only on plain `[Authorize]` without parameters.

Answer (score 2):

By default, all authorization requirements will be run through the `DefaultAuthorizatonService`, the source code and interface description for this can be found at:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/DefaultAuthorizationService.cs
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#iauthorizationservice

One of the cleanest options I can suggest to try is to register a custom implementation of this class and to override the AuthorizeAsync method to add the requirements for your default policy in any case where the authorization check includes any other requirements.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

public class CustomAuthorizationService : DefaultAuthorizationService
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationPolicyProvider _authorizationPolicyProvider;

    public CustomAuthorizationService(IAuthorizationPolicyProvider policyProvider, IAuthorizationHandlerProvider handlers, ILogger<DefaultAuthorizationService> logger, IAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory contextFactory, IAuthorizationEvaluator evaluator, IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
        : base(policyProvider, handlers, logger, contextFactory, evaluator, options)
    {
        _authorizationPolicyProvider = policyProvider;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement> requirements)
    {
        var def = await _authorizationPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
        if (requirements.Any()) requirements = requirements.Concat(def.Requirements); // If there are any requirements, also apply our default policy requirements
        return await base.AuthorizeAsync(user, resource, requirements);
    }
}
```

Then register this during startup with:
`services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationService, CustomAuthorizationService>();`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, unfortunately I can't use this because it combines only requirements but my policy also sets AuthenticationSchemas